# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL when adding Druidry as a dependency to my Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, jersey, dropwizard, druid

So I have been working on a dropwizard application. I had the controller working as I had wanted and now wanted to start implementing queries using Druid. I had wanted to use Druidry as a way to make queries through Java. My application works as desired without adding this dependency. However, simply adding this line

```
compile "in.zapr.druid:druidry:2.5"
```

causes this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$State.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:114)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:356)
at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig.<init>(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:55)
at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig.<init>(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:47)
at io.dropwizard.setup.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:80)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:37)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
at QueryApplication.main(QueryApplication.java:12)
```

At that line in my code, I have this written:

```
new QueryApplication().run(args);
```

I'm not sure why adding this one dependency is causing this issue, and I'm not even sure what this error means. Help please!

Comment: Look at the [pom for druidy](https://github.com/zapr-oss/druidry/blob/v2.5/pom.xml#L26). It shows it depends on Jersey 2.26.  Either you can update your Jersey dependencies to match this, or you can try to exclude all the Jersey deps from Druidy.

Answer (score 0):

Check if jersey version is compatible with your DropWizard version.
Also make sure that all jersey dependencies contain same version.